# New Page is not being rendered in the browser

Tags: php, laravel

Im new to laravel,

My home page is https://localhost/laravel/ and it correctly routes to

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Also i created a new html page 'about' 
with the routing

```
Route::get('about', function () {
    return view('about');
});
```

But https://localhost/laravel/about gives 404 error.

My HTAcess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
     AllowOverride All
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$` -> `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/public$`

Comment: I added the above mentioned line in .htacess file, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your "about" page must be where the "welcome" page exists and should has a "about.blade.php" name.

If "laravel" is the root directory (that contains "App", "bootstrap", "config" ... directories) then the about page must be in resources>views directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should create `about.blade.php` in `resources/views`